# ngmap - drawing a dynamic polygon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having an issue drawing a dynamic polygon using ngmap. Basically I have a map with an on-click event as follows

```
<map center="<% latitude %>, <% longitude %>" zoom="2" on-click="placeMarker()">
```

and the "placeMarker" method is inside my controller. Now, the following code will correctly place markers on the map and turn them into a polygon the moment you place the 4th marker...

```
$scope.placeMarker = function(e) 
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: e.latLng, map: $scope.map});

    $scope.coordinates.push( [Number(e.latLng.J),Number(e.latLng.M)] );

    if( $scope.coordinates.length == 4 )
    {
        $scope.createPolygon();
    } 


}

$scope.createPolygon = function()
{
    $scope.GoogleMap.polygons.push( $scope.coordinates );
    $scope.coordinates = [];
}
```

... but when I try to refactor the code to build the polygon when the user clicks back onto the first marker they placed nothing happens. The event listener fires, the logic appears OK but the polygon never appears

```
$scope.placeMarker = function(e) 
{
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: e.latLng, map: $scope.map});
    $scope.coordinates.push( [Number(e.latLng.J),Number(e.latLng.M)] );

    if( $scope.coordinates.length == 1 )
    {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

            $scope.createPolygon();
        });            
    } 
}

$scope.createPolygon = function()
{
    $scope.GoogleMap.polygons.push( $scope.coordinates );
    $scope.coordinates = [];
}
```

I'm sure this is probably a limitation in my generic JS knowledge. It has me stumped. Can anybody please advise?

Comment: `$scope.coordinates.length == 1` - is this a typo in second example?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time. No, I don't think so. I am attaching an event listener to the first marker.

Comment: You know that at the moment you click on marker, your `$scope.coordinates` will be full of `[Number(e.latLng.J),Number(e.latLng.M)]` right? If you expect it to have only one coordinate it won't work like that

Comment: $scope.coordinates hold an array of latitudes and longitudes. When ready I push the $scope.coordinates array onto the $scope.polygons array which has a two way data binding with the google map. The first example works so I think it's OK in principle(?)

Comment: First and second code snippets behave completely different, can you edit your question and write your expectations from the second code snippet please. That will help me to understand if i got your problem.